# Is it possible to use SimpleModal with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, simplemodal

Is it possible to use SimpleModal (jquery plugin) with ASP.NET MVC? Since it has postback stuff in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a jQuery plugin there's nothing to tie it to the ASP.NET postback model. It is server language agnostic. You can use it with PHP if you like as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394942/simple-modal-in-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just for the record, in the source, you need to change the container creation from appendTo('body'); to appendTo('form');